# Can I merge concurrent edits

Tags: discussion

Comedy of errors here

I edited a question to get rid of a scrollbar (I replaced tabs with 4 spaces).

Someone else committed a similar, but better correction, but my change was committed later, undoing their correction of the hex string (adding `";`).
OP then took my changes and added only the semicolon, not the quote.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19700880/revisions

An attempt to put that single character back in was refused due to the 6 character limit.  My standard approach there is to add or remove a comment
or language tag - but I consider that as a dirty hack.

Is there an easier way to merge (trivial) edits like these, or does that require a different privilege?

The real problem here is the challenge of collaboration with other anonymous users and I definitely don't want to use the comments for that.

BTW, in this case, the best solution would have been to retract my and OP's edits.

Comment: No way to merge edits that are already done. Most simple way in those rare cases is to rollback to the beginning and start over.

Comment: I think I found that option.  I rolled back to @sehe's version, and dropped the syntax hint.  `edit`, click `Rev` and select the revision

Comment: Yeah, [your suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3255512) is still pending, one user rejected it for some reason but we need one more to approve. EDIT: approved, all is good! :)